# System.BadImageFormatException: Невозможно загрузить файл или сборку Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, .net, windows-server

Написал приложение с использованием библиотеки [Newtonsoft.Json](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). При попытке запуска приложения из Visual Studio 2015 или 2013 — все работает, при попытке запуска на трех разных ПК (разные версии Windows и разные разрядности систем) вне среды VS — все работает, но при попытке запуска на двух разных (были заказаны у разных хостинг провайдеров) VPS KVM с Windows Server 2012 R2 x64 (.NET Framework установлен) — приложение не может загрузить библиотеку `Newtonsoft.Json.dll`. Проблема возникает только с этой библиотекой. Пробовал добавлять библиотеку в ресурсы и загружать их них — эффект тот же. Если из приложения убрать части кода, отвечающие за работу с JSON (то есть удалить использование самой библиотеки), то все прекрасно везде работает.

Ниже приведена ошибка, которая возникает при запуске:

```
System.BadImageFormatException: Невозможно загрузить файл или сборку "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" или один из зависимых от них компонентов. Ожидалось, что модуль содержит манифест сборки.
Имя файла: "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"
   в ***.***.ReadAllItemsInfo()
   в ***.Program.Main(String[] args) в C:\---\Program.cs:строка 55

=== Информация о состоянии предварительной привязки ===
Журнал: DisplayName = Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed
 (Fully-specified)
Журнал: Appbase = file:///C:/---/
Журнал: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Вызов сборки: SoketServer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.

Журнал: данная привязка начинается в контексте загрузки default.
Журнал: используется файл конфигурации приложения: C:\---\---.exe.Config.
Журнал: используется файл конфигурации главного узла: 
Журнал: используется файл конфигурации компьютера из C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
Журнал: ссылка после применения политики: Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed
Журнал: попытка загрузки нового URL file:///C:/---/Newtonsoft.Json.DLL.
Ошибка: не удалось завершить установку сборки (hr = 0x80131018). Проверка прекращена.

Void ReadAllItemsInfo()
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Подобная ошибка может быть в случае, если вы построили проект с AnyCpu, в то время как какая то из подключенных библиотек построена с x86\x64.

Как решать такую проблему можно узнать тут:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270531/how-to-determine-if-a-net-assembly-was-built-for-x86-or-x64

Так же рекомендую проверить версию .net фреймворка и проверить в конфиге версию рантайма:

```
<startup>
  <requiredRuntime version="v4.0.20506" safemode="true"/>
</startup>
```

Так же проверьте биндинги:

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-x.x.x.x" newVersion="x.x.x.x" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Answer (score 3):

Ответ выше мне никак не помог (вероятно потому, что у меня Sharepoint 2013, а не отдельное приложение), оказалось что стоило всего лишь добавить сборку в глобальный кэш сборок:

```
gacutil -i Newtonsoft.Json.dll
```

Утилиту gacutil нужно вызывать из Developer Command Prompt в папке Visual Studio.