# Не загружается .dll при размещении WCF-службы на IIS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, iis

Загружаю рабочую `WCF`-службу, которая работает с `Axapta`, на `IIS`. Служба загружается, но когда обращаешься к ней, возникает ошибка:

> Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку
>   "Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet" либо одну из их
>   зависимостей. Была сделана попытка загрузить программу, имеющую
>   неверный формат.

Если эту `dll` не загружать, функционал для работы с `Axapta` перестает работать, но сама служба загружается, и остальной функционал работает без проблем. С чем это может быть связано? Проверял на других `dll` - `Newtonsoft.Json.dll`, которая позволяет сериализовать в `JSON`-формат данные загружается без проблем, и служба работает.

Прилагаю трассировку стека:

```
 [BadImageFormatException: Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet" либо одну из их зависимостей. Была сделана попытка загрузить программу, имеющую неверный формат.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +234
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +108
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +25
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +34
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +49

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet" либо одну из их зависимостей. Была сделана попытка загрузить программу, имеющую неверный формат.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +772
System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +259
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +163
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +230
System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +76
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +343
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +176
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +734

[HttpException (0x80004005): Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet" либо одну из их зависимостей. Была сделана попытка загрузить программу, имеющую неверный формат.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +579
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +112
  System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +716
```

Comment: в собранном проекте присутствует Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet.dll? Проверьте еще, что в студии у референса на эту сборку стоит в свойствах Copy Local = true

Comment: @tCode, да, в самом проекте dll присутствует, весь функционал связанный с ней работает и отлажен, но при размещение на IIS, для дальнейшей связи службы с клиентом возникает ошибка. Если при публикации не указывать загружать эту dll - все работает, кроме, как указал, функционала с ней связанного. Указываю загружать - и ошибка

Comment: Посмотрите это: [System.BadImageFormatException](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/451257/189339), может быть поможет. Или это: [Could not load file or assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2160932/5275890)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [System.BadImageFormatException: Невозможно загрузить файл или сборку Newtonsoft.Json](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/451229/system-badimageformatexception-%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d1%83-newtonsoft)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, тоже так подумал, но тут библиотека другая и ошибка не совсем такая, какая возникла у автора.

Comment: @DenisBubnov что вы понимаете под "не совсем такая"? И при чем вообще тут другая библиотека?

Comment: ***Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet" либо одну из их зависимостей. Была сделана попытка загрузить программу, имеющую неверный формат.*** и с возможного дубликата ***Невозможно загрузить файл или сборку "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" или один из зависимых от них компонентов. Ожидалось, что модуль содержит манифест сборки.***  Надеюсь Вам удастся найти отличия.